# I am using an If statement depending on a relative column - cannot get it to work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am using google sheets. I have checkboxes in cells E1:AD1. When one of these checkboxes are checked, I want the cell in row 1 of that column to have the background coloured to green.

Eventually I want to be able to do the same to do different rows in the column. Please see my onEdit script below.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function onEdit(e) {

//This IF statement ensures that this onEdit macro only runs when cells E1:AD1 are edited in the sheet named "Finances 2020"
if (
e.source.getSheetName() == "Finances 2020" &&
e.range.columnStart == 5 &&
e.range.columnEnd == 30 &&
e.range.rowStart >= 1 &&
e.range.rowEnd <= 1 
) { 

//This if statement checks if the checkbox was checked or unchecked:
var checkboxtest = e.range.getValue()
if (checkboxtest == true) {

  //If so, colour the cell in row 1 of that column as green:
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Finances_2020 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Finances 2020");
  var Fortnightcolumn = e.range.columnStart      
  Finances_2020.getRange(1, Fortnightcolumn).setBackground('#d9ead3');

}else{

}
}
}
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to apply the background change for any edited cell in row 1, between the columns 5 and 30 - the correct statement would be:

`if (e.source.getSheetName() == "Finances 2020" && 5<=e.range.getColumn()<=30 &&
e.range.getRow() == 1)`

- Also, keep in mind that you enter the first `if` loop only if the sheet name is `Finances 2020`. Thus, to set the background color, you do not need to address the sheet separately, but can instead define `e.range.setBackground('#d9ead3');`.

SUMMARY

```
function onEdit(e) {
//This IF statement ensures that this onEdit macro only runs when cells E1:AD1 are edited in the sheet named "Finances 2020"
if (e.source.getSheetName() == "Finances 2020" &&
5<=e.range.getColumn()<=30 &&
e.range.getRow() == 1) { 
  //This if statement checks if the checkbox was checked or unchecked:
  var checkboxtest = e.range.getValue();
  if (checkboxtest == true) {
    //If so, colour the cell in row 1 of that column as green:
    e.range.setBackground('#d9ead3');
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to apply the background change also to other rows, e.g. rows 1 to 5 - change the condition of the if statement from `...&& e.range.getRow() == 1` to `...&& 1 <= e.range.getRow() <= 5`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the tips and advice too - very helpful!!!

Comment: Glad it helped!